# Is the DLC physically included with the Legendary Edition of Skyrim, or is it just a code?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I have an Xbox 360 and I am thinking about purchasing the Skyrim Legendary Edition. I was wondering if the included DLC would be on discs, or if there is just a code provided?

Answer (score 2):

If you buy the disc version of Legendary Edition for 360, it's on disc 2.

Answer (score 2):

In the Legendary Edition of Skyrim there are two physical discs where you can download the DLCs and there isn't a code. If you don't want to go through that hassle you can just buy it digitally through the xbox store which is probably what I would recommend making it easier on you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you purchase a physical edition, then the DLC and patch 1.9 are included on the discs. You can additionally choose to install none, some, or all of the DLC.

If you buy a digital edition, you'll obviously have no discs at all.